# pass model data to view

Tags: php, laravel

try to pass the model to view and I got error

model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cat extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table ='Cat';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cat;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CatController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $cats = Cat::all();

        return view('index', compact('cats'));
    }
```

and I try to check it in veiw

```
 {{dd($cats)}}
```

error message

> Undefined variable: cats (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommece\resources\views\app\template.blade.php)

Comment: You say that the name of the view is `index` when you do `view('index'` yet your filename is `template` and in a nested directory, which should be `app.template`, so nothing lines up here.

Comment: where are you calling this variable?? `index.blade.php` file or `template.blade.php`  file?

Comment: index extends from the template and I'm calling in the template 
```
//index file
@extends('app.template')

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Laravel works, when you pass data down to a view, it will only be available to that view and other blade files you include directly within that view as it will be within their scope, whereas the `template.blade.php` file isn't.

As far as I'm aware, your options will be to either to just access the `$cat` variable from within the index view or you can go to your BaseController which will be in this directory:

> app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

And in your constructor you could have something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $cats = Cat::all();

    View::share(['cats' => $cats]);
}
```

A word of warning, the second option does mean that the `$cats` variable will be available on every page load initiated by any controller that extends the base Controller so really, it would not be the most efficient approach as this does mean the database is being queried every time a page is loaded for all records of your Cat model, which may not actually be needed on every request.

Although, saying that you could also just use the constructor for the `CatController` in the same way to at least limit the Cat model being loaded for requests made to that controller.

In my option, It seems as though it may be worth considering the restructuring of your blade templates to make the usage of the `$cats` variable more feasible from within the `index.blade.php` view.

I hope this helps!